# Firestore query by date range

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I need the help to query long collection with date range. See the below example document. I wanna query startTime field using date range.

[image]

[image]

Comment: All these answers have a huge flaw: A query can only contain ">" or "<" one one field. This means that using this approach for filtering date, will then make it impossible to filter on ranges on other fields.

Answer (score 197):

Since I have the `dueDate` field stored as "timestamp" (and NOT as **string** or **number**) on Cloud Firestore, I did this to get the invoice documents with a due date on 2017:

```js
let start = new Date('2017-01-01');
let end = new Date('2018-01-01');

this.afs.collection('invoices', ref => ref
  .where('dueDate', '>', start)
  .where('dueDate', '<', end)
);
```

**NOTE:** `dueDate` field was stored at firebase with a Date() object. e.g.: `this.doc.dueDate = new Date('2017-12-25')`

Comment: If you take a screenshot of your firestore, is it possible from there to visually tell the difference between a datetime object or string?

Comment: Yes @DauleDK look: https://imgur.com/a/draQo the third field was filled with a Date() js object and it was stored as a timestamp (firebase made the convertion). And on the image you will see this timestamp formatted as UTC BUT I saved it as a Date object. And finally to check if this is really a timestamp field just hover the field. In my case I see "Marca de tiempo" which means "timestamp".

Comment: Wow that is awesome - something that should definitely be added to the firestore query documentation. I have this feeling that we will see many updates to the firebase-firestore console. "Marce de tiempo" - most valuable lesson learned today, gracias ;)

Comment: friends , i have try this but it returns nothing

Comment: Also, if you are using an additional equivalence query '==', you may need to enable a composite index, the best way to do this is by catching the error, which will output a Firebase link that you can follow to auto-setup the index. My request looks like this and needed a composite_index: ```.where('team_id', '==', teamId).where('time', '>=', start).where('time', '<=', end)```

Answer (score 46):

You could store the datetime object as [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since 1 January 1970). Then you can simple use the where select like this:

`collectionRef.where("startTime", ">=", "1506816000").where("startTime", "<=", "1507593600")`

Btw - to convert from datetime to Unix time in your app, you can use the excellent (now deprecated) library [moment](http://momentjs.com/)  (if you are building something with js or node).

Comment: thanks , but i have already data with date format just like the attached screenshot

Comment: Ok. According to firebase datetime is a supported data type in firestore. Is the startTime a string or datetime object?

Comment: it is dateTime object it is not string

Comment: can you take a screenshot from the firebase console - where you hover the mouse above your startTime - to see if datetime appear like here https://imgur.com/a/draQo

Comment: added to question new screenshot , it seems the data time is timestamp when i create the field using moment module

Comment: Hi @NimerFarahty - I just tried Capys answer on my own code with `new Date('2017-01-01')` and it seems to work great. Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes it is works , the problem is related to react-native-module and seems that  it is currently solved after upgrade to new version, appreciate your help thx @Capy

Comment: The standard is 8601 ISO, you can use strings to find.

Answer (score 32):

```js
    var startfulldate = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(1556062581000));
    db.collection('mycollection')
      .where('start_time', '<=', startfulldate)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {              
            var jsonvalue: any[] = [];
            snapshot.forEach(docs => {
              jsonvalue.push(docs.data())
               })
                 res.send(jsonvalue);
                 return;
                }).catch( error => {
                    res.status(500).send(error)
                });
```

Comment: Great ! You saved my life man. I just replaced admin.firestore by firebase.firestore and it worked.

Comment: This helped me immensely. I can't believe there's no documentation on Firebase for including dates in queries...

Answer (score 24):

```
const event = new Date();
const expirationDate = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(event);
const query = collectionRef.where('startTime', '<=', expirationDate)
```

Answer (score 13):

As `startTime` stored as `Timestamp`, you can do this query range for more accururate (this good for both condition of long date range or same date range).

```
const start = new Date('2021-01-01T00:00:00.000z');
const end = new Date('2021-03-01T23:59:59.000z');

db.collection('Data').where('startTime', '>=', start).where('startTime', '<=', end).get().then(data => {
   //pass your 'data' here
});
```

I used this in my Node.js apps. Hopefully this useful.

Answer (score 9):

For everyone recently using Firebase Firestore, there's a difference depending on your settings of your Firebase implementation (depending on the firebase version).

Before, Firestore was saving `Timestamp` as a `Date`, however as described [here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings#%7EtimestampsInSnapshots) the will be replaced soon by a `Timestamp` object. See the [Timestamp docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp).

You can force your implementation already by adding a setting in your code **to force Firebase to use Timestamp objects instead of Date** like this example:

```
var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: [APIKEY],
    authDomain: [FIREBASEAPPDOMAIN],
    projectId: [PROJECTID]
});

var firestore = firebase.firestore();
var settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true }; // force Timestamp instead of Date
firestore.settings(settings);
```

Comment: This is actually deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Firebase wants you to specify Timestamp objects specifically, going forward.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use Date.now(). Stop using timestamp service from Firebase, you need to work with the numerical value of the time in milliseconds like for example: 1514271367000, instead if Firestore uses 26/12/2017 1:56:07 GMT- 0500 (-05) will not work. An example of a query is:

```js
this.fsService.afs.collection('chats/4bY1ZpOr1TPq8bFQ3bjS/finance/123+finance/12345'
          , ref => ref.orderBy('hour').startAt(1514184967000).endAt(1514271367000))
          .valueChanges().subscribe(data =>{
            this.mensajes = data;
          })
```

Comment: Is it okay if Firestore saves Date.now() as number data? I feel like having date is better in some cases just because of that and easiness of understanding.

Comment: This appears to be Firebase Realtime Database code (e.g. it uses `startAt` and `endAt`) not Firestore code (which would use `where`, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)).  The two are similar, but not the same.

Comment: What is the timezone thought. When I determine the number, should I convert the datetime to GMT?

Answer (score 4):

Those who, like me, are using PHP to access Firestore, can do something like this:

```
$startTime = new DateTime('2020-05-23 00:00:00');
$endTime = new DateTime('2020-06-23 23:59:59');

$start = new Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp($startTime);
$end = new Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp($endTime);

// fb is a Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient object
$this->query = $this->fb->collection('your_collection');

$aux = $this->query;
$aux = $aux->where('startTime', '<', $end);
$aux = $aux->where('startTime', '>', $start);

return $aux->documents();
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Generic function to find documents in a collection by date range of specifics fields:

```
public List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> findDocsByDateRange(
                                          String collection, 
                                          String fieldStartDate,
                                          String fieldEndDate,
                                          Date startDate, 
                                          Date endDate) {
    ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot = fireStore()
        .collection(collection)
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(FieldPath.of(fieldStartDate), startDate)
                .whereLessThanOrEqualTo(FieldPath.of(fieldEndDate), endDate)
                    .get();
    return querySnapshot.get().getDocuments();
}
```

Packages:

```
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FieldPath;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
```

Answer (score -1):

In a frontend application, this is how Firebase timestamps and dates can be used to query and store documents.

[image: Firestore date usage]

Comment: Hello. As much as external links may be useful, please insert the content of your answer directly into SO.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you out,

```
yourMethod() {
    var date = DateTime.now();//
    print("First Date > " + DateTime(date.year, date.month, 1).toString());
    var datex = new DateTime(date.year, date.month + 1, 0);
    print("Last Date > " +datex);//
    //
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('biling')
        .where("driverId", isEqualTo: widget.uid)
        .where("date",
            isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                new DateTime(date.year, date.month, 1).toString())//1
        .where("date", isLessThanOrEqualTo: datex.toString())//2
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .getDocuments()
        .then(
          (QuerySnapshot snapshot) => {
            snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
              if (this.mounted) {
                setState(() {
                  totalP += double.tryParse(f.data["price"]);
                });
              }
              print("_price " + f.data["price"]);
              print("_duePaymntForCompay " + f.data["duePaymntForCompay"]);
            }),
          },
        );
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

**What worked for me was**
Format Date with Moment JS and split into Day, Month & Year

```
const currentDate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY").split("-");
const currentDay = currentDate[0];
const currentMonth = currentDate[1];
const currentYear = currentDate[2];


const allDocuments = await collectionRef
.doc(docId)
.collection(*COLLECTION NAME*)
.where(
  *DATE PARAMETER NAME*,
  ">=",
  new Date(`${currentYear}-${currentMonth}-${currentDay}`)
)
.where(
  *DATE PARAMETER NAME*,
  "<",
// ${parseInt(currentDay) + *Number of days you want in range*} 
  new Date(`${currentYear}-${currentMonth}-${parseInt(currentDay) + 1}`)
)
.get();
```