# How to automatically delete firestore documents which are created before N days?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have data structure like this:

Employees (Collection) > {EmployeeID} (Documents) > Chat (Collection) > {ChatId} (Documents).

In chat collection each document having 3 fields. 1. senderName, 2. sendTimestamp, 3. messageText.

I want to delete chats which are older than 7 days (from today).

I think it might be possible through cloud function but I am really basic user and don't know much about cloud functions. Please note that I don't want to make it automatically (cron job). I will do it manually on daily basis or whenever I wish.

I really searched a lot for this but its really hard. Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't tried anything because I really have very basic knowledge of cloud functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big part of this task involves querying a sub collection. You can read more about this idea here: [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)

There are basically two options at the time of writing this:

1. Query the entire top level collection (Employees) something like `db.collection('Employees').get()`. Then you would have to loop through each employ object querying for their sub collection (Chat) based on their date range. [Firestore query by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000854/firestore-query-by-date-range) for more reading on querying by a date in firestore. This could result in a large amount of reads depending on the number of Employee documents, but is the "easiest" approach in terms of not having to make changes to your data models/application.
2. Restructure your data to make the sub collection Chat a top level collection. Then you can do a query on this top level collection by the date. Less reads, but may not be as feasible depending on if this app is in production/willingness to make code changes.

A Function would definitely be able to accomplish this task either way you decide to approach it. One thing to note is that a Function executes using the Admin SDK, meaning it can basically ignore security rules set up on your Firestore.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think 1st option is helpful but amount of reads is really serious problem because I already have more than 5k records. Due to this existing data, your 2nd option is not useful.

Thanks for answer.