# Firestore query where date (timestamp) is more than 24 hours old

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a field in my document that is stored as a Timestamp like so

```
  "created_at": admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

What I want to do is find all documents using the admin lib in Cloud Functions, that have this field over 24 hours old

```
const tsToMillis = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis();
const results = await files.where("created_at", ">", tsToMillis - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).get();
```

I have tried the above, however I'm not sure how to get the value to compare it, or is there a way to do this directly with the Timestamp in FS without converting it?

Comment: I believe the best way is to actually create a new date object and use that in the query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000854/firestore-query-by-date-range

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
const tsToMillis = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis();
const compareDate = new Date(tsToMillis - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
const results = await files.where("created_at", "<", compareDate ).get();
```

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense thanks.  Just realised it'd be a `<` operator rather than `>` though :)