# Firestore SnapshotChanges - Listening for New Document

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am working on creating a realtime scrolling pagination service using Firestore. I plan to write it by loading in limit of 10 real-time documents to an array that will display on screen. When the loadMore() function is called, use the startAfter function to load 10 more *non-realtime* documents, etc. I got this idea from [Firebase's Youtube Channel](https://youtu.be/poqTHxtDXwU?t=396)

**The Idea... The Problem**

Once I load in some real-time documents, I want to listen for *new* documents in realtime, adding them or updating them in the array. `collectionRef.snapshotChanges()` emits a `DocumentChangeAction[]`. A single object in the array looks like this:

```
{
   doc: n {Df: e, E_: t, kf: n, Mf: false, Of: false, …}
   newIndex: 0
   oldIndex: -1
   type: "added"
}
```

It notates the last event the object experienced was `added`. Great but it doesn't notate when an object was `not-seen-in-this-query-before.-aka,-just-added-and-newly-loaded`.

**The Question**
Does anyone know how to find brand new objects in realtime via firestore?

Sidenote:
I could be approaching pagination all wrong but I believe this is a responsible way to achieve the task (that is, if it can be done this way).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual code that produced this behavior. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There has been no code written yet. The details of this question have been drawn from Firebase's Firestore documentation & Youtube Channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't maintain any sense of what a "new" document is.  It sounds like you should store a timestamp in each document that records when it was created.  You can then use this timestamp in a range filter to query for documents that are "new" by your definition.

If your definition of "new" is any document greater than the greatest timestamp seen in from a prior query, then just use that timestamp value in your query.  You can then listen to the results of that query to get any newer documents in real time.

See also: [Firestore query by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000854/firestore-query-by-date-range)

Comment: This might work. I can call a single `get()` for documents starting after the 10th document in the query. Use the timestamp of the 1st document in that `get()` to create a query of items greater than the timestamp - therefore creating a subscription of newly added documents. I appreciate your answer. It got my head spinning. I'll review the docs later today and mark this correct if it helped. 