# Firestore request with filter on timestamp property does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to execute ad-hoc requests on Firestore using a local node script:

```js
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'XXX',
    authDomain: 'XXX',
    projectId: 'XXX'
});

var db = firebase.firestore();

async function main() {
    var startTime = Date.parse('2020-09-03T12:56:00.000+02:00') / 1000;
    console.log('startTime = ', startTime)

    const ordersRef = db.collection('orders');
    const snapshot = await ordersRef
        // .where('uuid', '==', 'b4543f28-11c9-4aa5-b7c1-fabd344d5e4a')
        .where('created', '>=', startTime)
        .get();

    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No matching documents.');
        return;
    }

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log("%j", doc.data());
    });
}

main()
    .then(text => {
        console.log('finished');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error');
    });
```

When I perform the request with the condition `.where('uuid', '==', 'b4543f28-11c9-4aa5-b7c1-fabd344d5e4a')`, I have the expected response:

```
➜  ~/Projects/firestore  node adhoc.js
startTime =  1600356360
{"bid":"NhsrIsu8OLRqO80xfZmS","valid":true,"uuid":"b4543f28-11c9-4aa5-b7c1-fabd344d5e4a","created":{"seconds":1599130708,"nanoseconds":412000000}, ...}
finished
```

But when I execute the request with `.where('created', '>=', startTime)` instead (meaning: this where clause only), it somehow fails (no documents found), but I know there should be multiple results..

```
➜  ~/Projects/firestore  node adhoc.js
startTime =  1600356360
No matching documents.
finished
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**[UPDATE]**

Below, a screenshot of the timestamp value:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore has special type for Timestamp.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

You have 2 choice:

- Make `created` field as type number which hold the value `1600356360`. I sometime do this to avoid dependency of firebase type.
- Use `Date` object for comparison. No need to convert. `var startTime = Date.parse('2020-09-03T12:56:00.000+02:00');`

Comment: This answer may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000854/firestore-query-by-date-range

Comment: works great, thank you.. don't know why I so wanted to convert date to int.. if that may be helpful for the next person stuck on this problem, here's the syntax:
`.where('created', '>=', firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('2020-09-03T12:56:00.000+02:00')))`