# Filter results on the Firestore console by timestamp field

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

How can I filter the results on the [Firestore Console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console) by a timestamp field?

On the collection *users*, we have a field `createdOn` of type timestamp. If I want to filter the collection by field, I get the following dialog

[image: Filter 'user' collection by 'createdOn']

I have tried entering the date as string

- `2019-09-15`
- `2019-09-15T00:00:00Z`

I have also tried using a timestamp as number in millis and seconds

- `1568505600000`
- `1568505600`

When looking at the requests sent to Firestore, the [structured query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery) uses a [field filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery#FieldFilter) with a [value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/Value) of corresponding to either `stringValue` or `integerValue`, but I think the `timestampValue` would be the right thing.

I do not want to adapt the query in the console and build my own requests. I know that there is always the option to sort the documents in the collection and then scroll to where it's interesting, but this will load all documents that are not relevant.

Is there a simple way to do what I want?

Comment: In Firestore Console GUI its not possible to filter by timestamp. I think this GUI is only for support and testing purposes,  but it should be working in API.  If you need to use it in GUI I suggest to raise a feature request for it: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new [query builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#query_data) tab in the console (I do not know when this was introduced, but I assume during the [Firebase Summit 2022](https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/10/whats-new-at-Firebase-Summit-2022)). For the query above, this would look like this

[image: Firebase Console with Cloud Firestore, Data Tab / Query Builder]

It even has a timestamp type in the select list.